# JPA Criteria Query to find the MAX ID for each unique name

Tags: sql, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

EDIT:  Apparently my prior question was not sufficient so I will try to make it more clear with this try.

I have a set of rows in the table, selected by predicate **p1** below each of which have a unique value in the **id** column.  The **pathName** column may have multiple instances of the same value.   What want is to return only the entities that have a distinct **pathName** with the highest value **id**.

```
 CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<TextDocument> query = builder.createQuery(TextDocument.class);
 Root<TextDocument> root = query.from(TextDocument.class);

 // descending ids, and group similar names together

 query.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get(TextDocument_.id)));
 query.groupBy(root.get(TextDocument_.pathName));

 // filter

 Predicate p1 = builder.equal(root.get(TextDocument_.parent), rootdoc);
 Predicate p2 = builder.equal(root.get(TextDocument_.id), builder.max(root.get(TextDocument_.id)));
 query.where(p1, p2);
```

The predicate **p1** selects the documents that all have the same parent document and this of course works as long as it is by itself.

Predicate **p2** is all wrong, however.  Adding it causes an exception *ERROR 42903: Invalid use of an aggregate function.*.

The solution to a similar query problem is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554075/get-last-distinct-set-of-records)  in SQL but I want to do it using JPA Criteria Query.   I can't figure out how to make the nested SELECT syntax work.

To reiterate the problem with my own example I have the following data set

```
id  parent  pathName  
--- ------- --------- 
101     22  alpha
130     22  beta
250     22  charlie
251     22  alpha
339     22  beta
400     22  alpha
401     22  delta
```

The correct result (for parent=22) would be:

```
id  parent  pathName  
--- ------- --------- 
250     22  charlie
339     22  beta
400     22  alpha
401     22  delta
```

Can anyone help me finish this query?

Comment: What have you tried? What part of that SQL can't you replicate? JPQL and JPA Criteria require entities not tables and you havent posted it

Comment: @BillyFrost I restated the question with code does it make more sense to you now?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @AnchikaAgarwal I don't recall if we solved it in JPA.  Ultimately we converted the project to Elasticsearch so this problem was moot.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
SELECT * from [tableName] t1
WHERE not exists(SELECT * from [tableName]t2 where t1.name = t2.name and t2.id > t1.id)
```

Comment: The question asks for JPA Criteria ... is that JPA Criteria? Nope

Answer (score 1):

Using Reza example for sql:

```
SELECT * from [tableName] t1
WHERE not exists(SELECT * from [tableName]t2 where t1.name = t2.name and t2.id > t1.id)
```

And assuming the existing Root< TableEntity > root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, you can write the JPA Criteria:

```
Subquery<TableEntity> subQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(TableEntity.class);
Root<TableEntity> subQueryRoot = subQuery.from(TableEntity.class);
subQuery.select(subQueryRoot)
        .where(criteriaBuilder.and(
                criteriaBuilder.equal(subQueryRoot.get(TableEntity_.name), root.get(TableEntity_.name)),
                criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(subQueryRoot.get(TableEntity_.id), root.get(TableEntity_.id))
        ));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.exists(subQuery)));
```