# mySQL select latest distinct rows from table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table.

```
id  country     col1    col2    col3
1   country1    1   2   3
2   country1    2   2   1
3   country1    1   3   2
4   country2    3   2   2
5   country2    3   3   3
6   country3    3   2   2
7   country3    3   1   1
```

I am trying to output the last row of each distinct country.

```
id  country     col1    col2    col3
3   country1    1   3   2
5   country2    3   3   3
7   country3    3   1   1
```

I have tried various solutions such as:

```
select distinct(country), col1, col2, col3 from ( SELECT country, col1, col2, col3 from tablename order by id DESC) a limit 1
```

However, I cannot get the required output.

How can I obtain the latest distinct row for each country?

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554075/get-last-distinct-set-of-records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554075/get-last-distinct-set-of-records)

Answer (score 3):

You can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.id = (select max(t1.id) from mytable t1 where t1.country = t.country)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to get all the last ids with this query:

```
select max(id) from tablename group by country
```

and use it to return the rows that you want:

```
select * from tablename
where id in (select max(id) from tablename group by country)
```

or with not exists:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where country = t.country and id > t.id
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e709c84846c50cf2c3c4ec08db74702c).
Results:

```
> id | country  | col1 | col2 | col3
> -: | :------- | ---: | ---: | ---:
>  3 | country1 |    1 |    3 |    2
>  5 | country2 |    3 |    3 |    3
>  7 | country3 |    3 |    1 |    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all the elements in the table and in the WHERE condition filter by a in subquery, in that subquery just group by country:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tablename 
 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tablename  GROUP BY country)
```